# Is matrix exponential injective and surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

Exponential of real numbers exp: $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is injective. Does the same hold for exponential of real matrices exp: $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$? What about surjectivity, can every regular real matrix be written as $X=$ exp$A$?

Comment: What do you mean by regular matrix?

Comment: Invertible matrix, sorry, in my language it's called regular.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is neither injective nor surjective. Recall that $e^{2\pi i}=e^0=1$. We can replicate this example by letting 
$$
J:=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 &0 \end{bmatrix},$$ 
which satisfies $J^2=-I$, so 
$$
\exp(2\pi J)=I.$$ 
Since $I=\exp(0)$, the exponential is not injective.

The exponential is also not surjective as a map of the space of all matrices in itself, because the equation $\exp(X)=0$ has no solution. Even if one restricts the range to nonzero matrices, the exponential is still not surjective; one way to see it is to note that 
$$\tag{1}
\det \exp A= e^{\operatorname*{trace}(A)}\ne 0, $$
so if $Y$ is a matrix with $\det Y=0$, then the equation $\exp(X)=Y$ has no solution. (See [the Wikipedia page on the matrix logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Existence) for a precise description of the range of the exponential function).

*Remark*. Here's a proof of (1). If $A$ is diagonalizable, which means that 
$$
A=U\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & \ldots \\ 0& \lambda_2 & \ldots \\ \ldots & \ldots &\ldots\end{bmatrix}U^{-1}, $$ for some invertible matrix $U$, then (1) is immediate, because 
$$
\exp(A)=U \begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_1} & 0 & \ldots \\ 0& e^{\lambda_2} & \ldots \\ \ldots & \ldots &\ldots\end{bmatrix}U^{-1}, $$ 
so $\det \exp (A) = \prod e^{\lambda_j}=e^{\sum \lambda_j}$. The general case follows from this computation by continuity; indeed, the set of diagonalizable matrices is dense in the space of all matrices, both in the real and in the complex case.

Comment: You answered the question (+1), but now I wonder if you could characterize matrices $Y\ne0$ for which exp$(X)=Y$ has no solution.  I know that exp$(x)=y\in\mathbb R$ has no solution when $y<0$.  Does it have to do with the sign of det$(Y)$ or positive-definite or something like that?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Good question, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix). (Added link to the body of the answer).

Comment: Thanks again, @Giuseppe Negro.  So indeed if $Y\in \mathbb R^{2\times2} $ and det$(Y)< 0$, there is [no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Constraints_in_the_2_%C3%97_2_case) $X\in \mathbb R^{2\times2}$ such that exp$(X)=Y$